# Transform array of objects from one form to another with simple lodash/underscore functions

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I have a JavaScript array in the following format:

```
[{key: '123', data: ['a', 'b', 'c']}, {key:'234', data: ['b', 'c', 'd']}];
```

Expected Result:

```
[{a: '123'}, {b:['123', '234'}, {c:['123', '234']}, {d:['234']}]
```

I tried `groupBy`, `map`, `reduce`, and couple of other lodash functions, but nothing returns close to what I need.

Comment: Why do you want them as an array instead of a single object?

Comment: Thats how I need to send to the server :)

Comment: The pattern of what you are trying to do is not really leaping out at me.

Answer (score 0):

### Following code works, but I don't like using two for loops. I am sure there is a better way to do this. Please suggest.

var inputArr = [{key: '123', data: ['a', 'b', 'c']}, {key:'234', data: ['b', 'c', 'd']}];

```
var outputArr = [];
var tempObj = {};
angular.forEach(inputArr, function(obj) {
    var key = obj.key;
    angular.forEach(obj.data, function(data) {
        tempObj[data] = {'data': data, 'key': key};
    });
});
outputArr = _.map(tempObj, function(value, index){
  return {'data': index, 'key': value};
});
```

---

```
//[{a: '123'}, {b:['123', '234'}, {c:['123', '234']}, {d:['234']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for lulz =) :

```js
var t = [{key: '123', data: ['a', 'b', 'c']}, {key:'234', data: ['b', 'c', 'd']}];
var r = {};
var k = _.each(_.uniq([].concat.apply([], _.pluck(t, 'data'))), function(p){
    r[p] = _.pluck(_.filter(t, function(n){return n.data.indexOf(p) > -1}), 'key');
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

Result (as object):

```js
{"a":["123"],"b":["123","234"],"c":["123","234"],"d":["234"]}
```

And:

```js
var r = [];
var k = _.each(_.uniq([].concat.apply([], _.pluck(t, 'data'))), function(p){
    var q = {};
    q[p] = _.pluck(_.filter(t, function(n){return n.data.indexOf(p) > -1}), 'key');
    r.push(q);
});
```

Result (as array):

```js
[{"a":["123"]},{"b":["123","234"]},{"c":["123","234"]},{"d":["234"]}]
```